# D7: images are not displayed on first page load after image-flush

Tags: image, drupal-7

I'm having an issue that after clearing image styles, images are not displayed and seem as broken links even links are healthy when checked from firebug. However after refreshing the page images are back to normal and displayed correctly. Permissions and ownership are correct for sites/default/files folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out if you have missed a blank line before opening or after closing php tags. The chances of missing it with index.php, template.php etc. files

Comment: Yes, I missed a blank line in settings.php file.